# HTTP ERROR 500 after upload laravel 8 project

Tags: php, laravel

i have upload my laravel 8 project but i got error 500 i have upload the files in main directory of the server i mean there is no public_html folder in this server

**i have tried in public/index.php these code but it not work**
to add  ../../  on this line `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';`
**this is public/index.php file**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If The Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is in maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command
| we will load this file so that any pre-rendered content can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**and i add htaccess with the code file in between the files and doesn't work**

Comment: You are giving not enough info. By default laravel expects the web root to be `/public`.

Answer (score 0):

first way go to .env and set

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

and see the problem

Comment: it is like that correct